# In Django prevent deletion or editing of a single default record

Tags: django, django-models

I am using Django 1.6 version and I have a Django model for which i want to add a default record. I can add that record using fixtures or sql, but i want to prevent that particular record from being deleted.
In the admin panel i should see the record say as disabled so that no user can edit or delete only that record. They can edit or delete other records.

Is this possible?

I tried looking at get_actions or has_delete_permission but that apply to all records and not just the single default record

Comment: `has_delete_permission` takes `obj` as an optional argument if you wish to prevent deletion of certain objects

Comment: Thanks a lot. That does partly solve the problem. I get Forbidden message if i open that record. But in the list view i can select the item and then select 'Delete selected item' from the Action drop down and still delete the item. How do i prevent this too for the same record only?